# do.call(), multiple parameters

Tags: r, lapply, do.call

I have a function with many arguments:

fun(A,B,C,D,E)

Now I want to assign fixed value `a,b,c,d` to `A,B,C,D` and assign E a list of 1 : 7

I want to use `do.call()` as below, but it doesn't work.

```
a <- do.call(function(x) fun(A = a, B = b, C = c, D = d, E = x), list(1:7))
```

I turn to lapply, and it works,

```
a <- lapply(c(1:7), function(x) fun(A = a, B = b, C = c, D = d, E = x))
```

As Joshua Ulrich's answer, when I try

```
a `<- do.call(fun, list(A = a, B = b, C = c, D = d, E = list(1:7)))`
```

it says

```
(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

So I guess fun needs a double value for E, but do.call() doesn't give the values one by one, but a list.

I don't want to use `lapply` because it returns a list of list, which, if I want to point at a special list, I have to use [[]], and only single value is allowed in [[]], and I cannot use a vector to point at, e.g. [[a]],with a <- c(1:7).

How to make do.call() work?

Comment: Why don't you use `lapply` since it works? I think you have misunderstood why/how to use `do.call` - it is not supposed to do the same thing as `lapply`... Can you provide `fun` and the desired output?

Comment: @konvas Thanks, I have edit the question, showing why I don't want to use lapply.... for do.call, is it suppose to apply function with different parameters?

Comment: OK, so you should keep using `lapply` but then you can simplify your result, depending on the format you want it to have. For example, you can covert this list  `x <- list(1, 2, 3)` to the vector `c(1, 2, 3)` simply by `unlist(x)`. It really depends on the format of the output of `lapply` and what you want to convert it to (`sapply` does some automatic simplification which may or may not work for you, I tend to avoid it)

Comment: By the way, vector subscripts do work with lists, but with single square bracket. Try for example `list(1, 2, 3, 4)[2:3]`

Comment: @konvas Thanks, the problem is the result is like this. a <- list(listA,listB,listC), for A,B,C, they are also a list with 6 lists. if I unlist(a)....then all the list will disappear. For my goal is just to get listA (which a[[1]] gives back), not a list of listA (which a[1] gives back).....this really annoys me every time I use lapply. sometime I will use sapply instead, but for this case, sapply cannot get what I want....that's why I turn to do.call()

Comment: I see. In `unlist` there is an argument `recursive` which you can try setting to `FALSE`. In any case I mentioned `unlist` just to give you an example, as I said it totally depends on what list you have and what you want to convert it to. If you want to post an exact `dput` of your list and the desired outcome, I can try to help. The point is that `do.call` is completely irrelevant here because it is not designed to do what you want

Answer (score 3):

That should be:

```
a <- do.call(fun, list(A = a, B = b, C = c, D = d, E = list(1:7)))
```

And I have a feeling you want `E` to be a vector, not a list, in which case it should be:

```
a <- do.call(fun, list(A = a, B = b, C = c, D = d, E = 1:7))
```

Comment: those don't work for me....for first case, it says cannot coerce a list to double, which I think that, maybe they need a double value there....second, no error, but the result is wrong...

Comment: Then you need to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).